# How to find the second string and get after its value (duplicate)

Tags: php

I have a line of string which contain only number. I would like to build a function to search a check-in date and out date which I have retrieve from G-mail. by that way I want to get all number after the position tow of 2015 which you can see the the $html below. Exactly You will see a few number of 2015 in the string (6) the first number of 2015 is not important but I want get the number of 2015 in the second position and all number after.

Default :

```
$html = "02122015061155201506192015062120150617012015061720150617010";
```

After :

"2015061155201506192015062120150617012015061720150617010"

I tried strstr until now but it does now work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$htmlarray = explode("2015", $html, 1);
$newhtml = "2015" . $htmlarray[1];
```

I couldn't really understand which 2015 you wanted the information after as in the question you said the second but the string is after the first.  Either way just modify the above.

Edited to add: If you are looking for the first instance than strstr is the way to go.  Make sure it is treating it as string and not an int.

Answer (score 1):

Everything should work simply using strstr as follows.

```
<?php
$html = "02122015061155201506192015062120150617012015061720150617010";
$modified = strstr($html, "2015");
?>
```

Does the $modified value not give what you are looking for?